# Postgresql: notification if a view is modified

Tags: database, postgresql, view, triggers

I'm building a quite complex database and in order to simplify some queries I made a view that involves a lot of joined tables. I need to receive a notification whenever a row is added / modified / deleted in the view. Using postgresql 9.2 I first though about the new feature: triggers on view, introduced in pg 9.1. However this doesn't do what I need, since this feature only offers a trigger that is fired when an insert/update/delete is performed directly on the view.

Long story short: I need something (triggers or else) that, looking directly on the view, will notify me when my view is updated (I mean indirectly: when one of the tables which composes the view is modified). Is there something easy to use or I have to manually set a trigger for each table that is involved in the creation of the view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at this from a higher level.  Use source control and create any kind of notification system you want as database objects are checked in and out.

Comment: "When a table is modified" usually means someone's executed an ALTER TABLE statement. But that's not what you're talking about, is it? You're talking about being notified of changes to data in the tables that the view is built on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature what you want doesn't exist. You need to write your own a set of triggers on interesting tables.